# Problems with uv when using half pixel translations

Tags: opengl, shader

I am rendering 2 triangles to make a square, using a single draw call with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.

I calculate position and uv in the shader with:

```
vec2 uv = vec2(gl_VertexID >> 1, gl_VertexID & 1);
vec2 position = uv * 333.0f;
float offset = 150.0f;
mat4 model = mat4(1.0f);
model[3][1] = offset;
gl_Position = projection * model * position;
```

projection is a regular orthographic projection that matches screen size.

In the fragment shader I want to draw each first line of pixels with blue and each second line of pixels with red color.

```
int v = int(uv.y * 333.0f);
if (v % 2 == 0) {
    color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
} else {
    color = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

This works ok, however if I use offset that will give me a subpixel translation:

```
offset = 150.5f;
```

The 2 triangles don't get matching uvs as seen in this picture:

[image: 2 neighboring triangles get different uv]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute interpolation is done only with a finite precision. That means that due to round-off errors, even a difference in `1 ulp` (unit-last-place, i.e. least significant digit) can cause the result rounded to the other direction. Since the order of operations in the hardware interpolation unit can be different between the two triangles, the values prior to rounding can be slightly different. OpenGL does not provide any guarantees about that.
For example you might be getting `1.499999` in the upper triangle and `1.50000` in the lower triangle. Consequently when you add an offset of `0.5` then `1.99999` will be rounded down to `1.00000` but `2.000000` will be rounded to `2.00000`.

If pixel perfect results are important to you I suggest you calculate `uv` coordinates manually from the `gl_FragCoord.xy`. In a case of an axis-aligned rectangle, as in your example, it is straightforward to do.

Comment: But the triangles are using the exact same numbers, how could there be round-off errors?

Comment: @RhuMage: To interpolate the attributes OpenGL has to calculate the barycentric coordinates of each fragment within the triangle. The barycentric coordinates of the same fragment, naturally, is different for the two triangles, so the calculations aren't really the same: for the first triangle it has to interpolate `uv` from vertices `0,1,2`, for the second from vertices `2,0,3`. See [how OpenGL interpolates attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460895/277176), it talks about the general perspective case but the pipeline still does the same math for 2d projections, just with constant `w=1`.

Comment: Is it possible this is a driver bug? I tested on 5 nvidia cards and 3 amd cards all with latest drivers. 2 out of 3 amd had this problem while none of nvidia had it.

Comment: @RhuMage: It's not a bug -- there's nothing that guarantees that in the spec so it can happen. I experienced that on nvidia cards too. Just use `gl_FragCoord`.