# OpenGL fragment interpolation formula

Tags: glsl

I'm curious about how does OpenGL transform vertices output to fragments input by fragment interpolation. Could anyone post the formula or algorithm of how does OpenGL do fragment interpolation?

Comment: That depends on the [Interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly does OpenGL do perspectively correct linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441631/how-exactly-does-opengl-do-perspectively-correct-linear-interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the [Interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers). For a detailed explanation see [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification (HTML) - 4.5. Interpolation Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#interpolation-qualifiers).

By default (`smooth`) the interpolation is done in a perspective correct manner.
See [How exactly does OpenGL do perspectively correct linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441631/how-exactly-does-opengl-do-perspectively-correct-linear-interpolation).

But the interpolation can be changed. If the qualifier `flat` is explicitly specified, no interpolation takes place at all. The value given to the fragment shader is the value from the [Provoking Vertex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Provoking_vertex) of the corresponding primitive.
`noperspective` causes a linear interpolation.

Comment: Could you give some simple example formula for vec and integer of interpolation between out from vertex shader and in at fragment shader?

Comment: See [How exactly does OpenGL do perspectively correct linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441631/how-exactly-does-opengl-do-perspectively-correct-linear-interpolation)