# Perspective-correct texture-mapping in my graphics engine

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, game-engine

I have written a 3D graphics engine in Java many years ago. It has texture mapping, but it does not account for the depth, so it's incorrect. See the attached screenshot, paying attention to the ground:

[image: Screenshot of example with a perspective-incorrect mapping of the ground texture onto the screen]

The entire code is here: [GitHub repository](https://github.com/r-c-s/Feyn3d)

And I believe the fix would be somewhere in this class, `TexturedPolygon3dRenderer`:

```java
package rcs.feyn.three.render.renderers;

import java.util.Optional;

import rcs.feyn.color.ColorUtils;
import rcs.feyn.math.MathUtils;
import rcs.feyn.math.Vector2d;
import rcs.feyn.math.Vector3d;
import rcs.feyn.three.gfx.Graphics3d;
import rcs.feyn.three.gfx.TextureRaster;

public class TexturedPolygon3dRenderer {

  public static void render(
      Graphics3d graphics,
      Vector3d[] deviceCoordinates,
      double intensity,
      Optional<int[]> colors,
      TextureRaster textureData,
      Vector2d[] textureCoordinates,
      int alpha) {

    if (deviceCoordinates.length != 3) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only render triangles");
    }

    Vector3d va = deviceCoordinates[0];
    Vector3d vb = deviceCoordinates[1];
    Vector3d vc = deviceCoordinates[2];

    double xa = va.x();
    double xb = vb.x();
    double xc = vc.x();
    double xd = (xa+xb+xc)/3;

    double ya = va.y();
    double yb = vb.y();
    double yc = vc.y();
    double yd = (ya+yb+yc)/3;

    double za = va.z();
    double zb = vb.z();
    double zc = vc.z();
    double zd = (za+zb+zc)/3;

    double u1 = xb - xa;
    double v1 = xc - xa;
    double u2 = yb - ya;
    double v2 = yc - ya;
    double u3 = zb - za;
    double v3 = zc - za;

    double aa = u2*v3 - u3*v2;
    double bb = u3*v1 - u1*v3;
    double cc = u1*v2 - u2*v1;

    double dInvZdx = -aa/cc;
    double dZdy = -bb/cc;

    int screenW = graphics.getRaster().getWidth();
    int screenH = graphics.getRaster().getHeight();

    int ymin = MathUtils.roundToInt(MathUtils.max(MathUtils.min(ya, yb, yc), 0));
    int ymax = MathUtils.roundToInt(MathUtils.min(MathUtils.max(ya, yb, yc), screenH));

    boolean interpolateColor = colors.isPresent();

    int tdw = textureData.getWidth();
    int tdh = textureData.getHeight();

    for (int y = ymin; y <= ymax; y++) {
      double ximin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      double xjmin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      double xkmin = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      double ximax = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      double xjmax = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      double xkmax = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      if ((y - yb) * (y - yc) <= 0 && yb != yc) {
        ximax = xc + (y - yc)/(yb - yc) * (xb - xc);
        ximin = ximax;
      }
      if ((y - yc) * (y - ya) <= 0 && yc != ya) {
        xjmax = xa + (y - ya)/(yc - ya) * (xc - xa);
        xjmin = xjmax;
      }
      if ((y - ya) * (y - yb) <= 0 && ya != yb) {
        xkmax = xb + (y - yb)/(ya - yb) * (xa - xb);
        xkmin = xkmax;
      }

      int xmin =
          MathUtils.roundToInt(MathUtils.max(MathUtils.min(ximax, xjmax, xkmax), 0));
      int xmax =
          MathUtils.roundToInt(MathUtils.min(MathUtils.max(ximin, xjmin, xkmin), screenW));

      double invZ = zd + (y - yd) * dZdy + (xmin - xd) * dInvZdx;

      for (int x = xmin; x < xmax; x++, invZ += dInvZdx) {
        Vector3d bary = RenderUtils.cartesianToBarycentric(x, y, va, vb, vc);

        Vector2d interpolatedTextureCoordinate = RenderUtils.barycentricToCartesian(
            bary, textureCoordinates[0], textureCoordinates[1], textureCoordinates[2]);

        double textureX = interpolatedTextureCoordinate.x();
        double textureY = interpolatedTextureCoordinate.y();

        int textureXInt = MathUtils.clamp((int) textureX, 0, tdw - 1);
        int textureYInt = MathUtils.clamp((int) textureY, 0, tdh - 1);

        int pixel = textureData.getPixel(textureXInt, textureYInt);

        int colorWithIntensity = ColorUtils.mulRGB(pixel, intensity);

        if (interpolateColor) {
          int[] colorz = colors.get();

          int interpolatedColor = ColorUtils.addRGBA(
              ColorUtils.mulRGBA(colorz[0], bary.x()),
              ColorUtils.addRGBA(
                  ColorUtils.mulRGBA(colorz[1], bary.y()),
                  ColorUtils.mulRGBA(colorz[2], bary.z())));

          colorWithIntensity = ColorUtils.blendRGB(
              colorWithIntensity,
              interpolatedColor,
              intensity);
        }

        int finalColor = ColorUtils.setAlphaToRGBA(colorWithIntensity, alpha);

        graphics.putPixel(x, y, invZ, finalColor);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if I can provide more info. Unfortunately, I wrote this such a long time ago, and I don't understand the mathematical details anymore. I should have documented it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `RenderUtils.cartesianToBarycentric` calculates the barycentric coordinates of the pixel corresponding to the already projected triangle. However, you need the barycentric coordinates of the point that is covered by the pixel and lies within the triangle before the projection (so everything in 3D space). You can get the barycentric coordinates in clip space relatively easily, as it is explained very well in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460895/20216198

Comment: oh my god! I got it! THANK YOU SO MUCH! IT'S BEAUTIFUL!